# No member named 'ShareableValue' in namespace 'reanimated'

Tags: ios, react-native, camera, react-native-reanimated, react-native-vision-camera

While using react-native-vision-camera I got such an error, when I have tried to compiling my code in iOS and this gives me an error, I am using

```
 "react-native": "0.71.10",
 "react-native-reanimated": "^3.3.0",
```

anyone help me to figure this out and fix this issue

[image]

Comment: Downgrade react-native-reanimated to 2.14.4 and run pod install source (https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/issues/1503)

Comment: Thank you @Chandaboy., after downgrading react-native-reanimated to 2.14.4., react-native-vision-camera working fine